How does a photon look like in QFT?
It is very well known that in QFT the particles are excitations of the field. But how exactly is a free photon looking like in spacetime? What is it shape in free space? And what is in fact in the excited area? I will not post suggestions. Just wanna read how physicists imagine it.

It looks like an electromagnetic wave

QFT is relativistic QM, in that sense photons in QFT inherit the particle-wave duality view from QM.

Do you mean a photon on the visible spectrum or to either side of it?

A photon is the electromagnetic field you're used to. If you add more photons, the field strength increases. The field strength is uncertain, because the number of photons in a location is uncertain. In the limit of large $N$, the uncertainty decreases and you get classis electric/magnetic fields.

@AccidentalTaylorExpansion Photon in QFT is excitaton of the EM field which is basic element of reality. The classical EM is a huge collection of many coherent photons. So a photon can not the classical field. Rather the opposite.

@LuckyCharms In that sense this excitaton is probabilistic like the WF in QM. How is than worth the statement that this excitaton is real e.g. has observable effects on different points in space?

@BySymmetry I am concerned about the shape of single photon or the shape in which QEM field is excited and how it spreads in free. I think that It is an expanding sphere with velocity c. But how thick it is I am not sure. Just a math sphere of thickness zero? There are experiments where two time-shifted photons interfere in MZI.

Are you familiar with the QFT treatment of the free electromagnetic field? Are you comfortable with the general form of a one-particle  state (i.e. the state describing a single photon)  given by $\sum_\lambda \int d\mu(k) f(\vec{k},\lambda) a^\dagger(\vec{k},\lambda)|0\rangle$, where $f(\vec{k})$ is the wavefunction of the photon in momentum space? Do you know how to compute the expectation value of a local operator in such a state? Or are you simply looking for some vague qualitative "answer"? Without telling us your physical background knowledge, it is hard to give an adequate answer.

@Hyperon Math doesn't make things clear for me from physical point of view. What gives you momentum space formulation is just saying that there is a superposition of plane waves living in whole configuration space which for single excitaton is space itself. They extinguish everywhere except in just some region. Does the formula giveswhat the region is and how it evolves? How do you connect expectation values with a momentpicture of the excitaton. I am well acquainted with math side of QFT though I very much lack physical view. Do you think it's better to only stick to math and just calculate?

The second sentence of your comment gives me the suspicion that you are mixing up the properties of a coherent state of the electromagnetic field (being a coherent superposition of $n$-particle states) with those of a one-particle state (describing a single photon). The expectation value of the electromagnetic field (operator) for the coherent state (describing a "classical" field configuration) is indeed a superposition of plane waves. On the other hand, its expectation value for the single photon state vanishes. For the question of "localization" you need  a suitable field bilinear.
